# Get Highest high and lowest low in every last Moving Average Cross like ZigZag

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to code an indicator that plots the highest high and lowest low between each moving average crosses. Like a ZigZag indicator.

For example if the fast MA crosses the slow MA from below, the indicator should be looking for the highest high only and there should be only one value between the crosses. The same for a cross from above, the indicator should be plotting only one value which is the lowest low since the last cross.

I am new to Pine script, but not new to coding in general. I find it challenging to code the simplest things with Pine script. I am learning how to code in this language.

Please help direct me on how to find the correct answer. Thank you

```
//@version=4
study(title="MA Cross", overlay=true, max_bars_back=3000)

MA1 = sma(close, 20)
MA2 = sma(close, 100)

Highest(src, len) =>
    max = high
    for i = 1 to len
        if src[i] > max
            max := src[i]
    max

Lowest(src, len) =>
    min = src[0]
    for i = 1 to len
        if src[i] < min
            min := src[i]
    min

HH = 0.0
HH := Highest(high, barssince(cross(MA1, MA2)))

LL = 0.0
LL := Lowest(low, barssince(cross(MA1, MA2)))

HighLow = 0.0

if(MA1 > MA2)
    HighLow := HH
else
    if(MA1 < MA2)
        HighLow := LL
    else
        HighLow := na


plot(series=HighLow, color = color.red, linewidth=3)
plot(series=MA1, color = color.aqua, linewidth=1)
plot(series=MA2, color = color.orange, linewidth=1)
```

Comment: So. what's your problem?

Comment: That code doesn't work like expected. I need to have the lines be plotted on the highest high and the lowest low between each two Moving average crosses. The issue is the lines are plotted on the high of every candle between the 2 crosses. There should be only one point (highest high) between two crosses and one point (lowest low) between the next two crosses.Like a zig zag indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but, the problem seems to be related to the fact that `barssince()` returns `series[integer]` and when you use that in `for` condition, it causes problems.

So, you need to implement your own `barssince()`. I used a simple counter for that.

```
//@version=4
study(title="MA Cross Debug", overlay=false, max_bars_back=3000)

MA1 = sma(close, 20)
MA2 = sma(close, 100)

var cntA1LessThanA2 = 0
HighestCross = 0.0

MovingAverage_Long  = crossover(MA1, MA2) 

Highest(src, len) =>
    max = high
    for i = 1 to len
        if (src[i] > max)
            max := src[i]
    max

if (MA1 > MA2)
    cntA1LessThanA2 := cntA1LessThanA2 + 1
else
    cntA1LessThanA2 := 0

if (MA1 > MA2)
    HighestCross := Highest(high, cntA1LessThanA2)

else
    HighestCross := na

plot(series=barssince(MA1<MA2), title="barssince", color=color.green, linewidth=3)
plot(series=cntA1LessThanA2, title="cntA1LessThanA2", color=color.red, linewidth=3)
```

[image]

In the indicator below in the screenshot, I plot the counter (red) and return value of `barssince()` (green), to show you counter works as expected.

```
plot(series=barssince(MA1<MA2), title="barssince", color=color.green, linewidth=3)
plot(series=cntA1LessThanA2, title="cntA1LessThanA2", color=color.red, linewidth=3)
```

Note that, your indicator will not have a valid output `if MA >= M1` because you are asigning `na` to `HighestCross` in that case. But I guess you already know that.

```
if (MA1 > MA2)
    HighestCross := Highest(high, cntA1LessThanA2)

else
    HighestCross := na

plot(HighestCross, color = color.red, linewidth = 3)
```

I believe you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you Baris for your answer. barsince() function does cause issues with the indicator. I tested the code you wrote and tried to make it work but it didn't give the right answer.

Comment: The only issue with the code below is the indicator need to assign na to all the values that are not the highest high. 


`//@version=4
study(title="MA Cross", overlay=true, max_bars_back=3000)

MA1 = sma(close, 20)
MA2 = sma(close, 100)

Highest(src, len) =>
    max = high
    for i = 1 to len
        if src[i] > max
            max := src[i]
    max
    
o = 0.0

o := Highest(high, barssince(cross(MA1, MA2)))

plot(series=o, title="Highest High", color = color.green, linewidth=3)`

Comment: Hi @TheTraddder, either edit your question and put this piece of code there or ask a new question. It is difficult to read code snippets from the comments. If you believe the issue you have now is not related to the original question, I suggest you ask a new question. Normally we have "one question per post" rule here.

Comment: Thanks Baris. I will edit my post with the best code I could come up with. It's actually very near to the desired result.

Comment: Can I ask the same question in a new post @Baris Yakut ?